# Large files: impossible to read when they are on an external HD

Tags: c#, io, filestream, hard-drive

I've this simple code:

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\test.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
    int n = fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

that normally works as expected returning the array of bytes at the beginning of the file.

Incredibly when I try to read a quite large file (~7GB) located on an external HD connected through USB, the bytes in the returned array are all zeros  *and* n is 100.

If I try a file of the same type but smaller everything works fine. If I try the same big file on another external HD I have, again everything is fine. Even more incredibly, **if I try the same big file and I use the same external HD that gives me problems but connected through eSATA everything works fine**!

Both HDs are NTFS and the described behavior on the problematic HD is not 100% stable: sometimes files around 7GB are not read, sometimes they are; files around 10GB are never read.

Any idea on what can cause this and how to solve it?

---

EDIT:
I've tried by reading 1GB of data and nothing changes. But here there are other hints: if the file is too large the time for reading 1GB of bytes is too short to be a real reading; moreover if I wait the HD to go in standby mode and if I try to read 1GB from a small file the HD exits standby, the reading takes time and succeeds, while if I try with a large file the HD does not exit the sleep mode, the reading takes few milliseconds and again all zeros.

If I initialize the byte array with some values, those values are erased after the "fake" reading and again I've all 0's.

Comment: What if you do a `fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` before reading?

Comment: @AlvinWong Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried it out but with no success.

Comment: wow... have you tried reading amounts larger than 100 bytes? say 1MB or even 1GB? i'm curious to find out what's really happening...

Comment: oh and just to make sure.... are you sure that the first 100 bytes are indeed NOT 0's?

Comment: @khovanskiiªn. Thanks. I've edited accordingly to your suggestion. And yes I'm sure the bytes are not 0's since I copied and pasted the file on another HD where the reading worked out.

Comment: so this seems to be a crappy USB/hardware issue.. time for lunch! :D

Comment: How about try initializing `bytes` with some pattern and see if they are overwritten by *zeros*?

Comment: Is the problematical hard drive a SSD or something odd like that?

Comment: @AlvinWong Interestingly, they are overwritten!

Comment: @Bobson it's not SSD, it's a normal HD. But it is not the only one. I mean is the only one I have, but I've started these tests since a user of my app is experiencing the same problem with other 2 HDs he has.

Comment: Can other programs read the file okay? If other programs can read it but your program can't, then I'd suspect your code. If other programs have the same problem, then it's almost certainly a hardware issue.

Comment: @JimMischel ok I've tried with a hex editor and it displays all zeros too. Then as you said it is an hw problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that same code work fine with some drives, and you have no control on how your drive works thru USB or whatever, I guess it's just a hardware problem. Try to run program with the same drives on another computer.

Comment: Ok thanks, it is an hw problem, but even in this case I would not have expected to have n = 100(the number of read bytes). In my opinion n should be 0.

Comment: @Ganswer Windows just read the file content, it doesn't know it is a hw problem, so whatever it receives from the underlying drivers it will return them to you.